# How to access the BIOS - ThinkPad x120e?

Tags: windows-7, bios

I want to access **BIOS** on my **ThinkPad x120e**. I have tried to do it several ways like pressing `F1` button for couple times, but it doesn't access the **BIOS** anyway.

> How can I access the BIOS on ThinkPad x120e?

**NOTE:** I'm using Windows 7

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you power on your computer, there should be a message that says "Press F1 to enter setup" or it might say "Press ESC to interrupt normal boot process". At this point, you should be prompted to enter the BIOS.

Needless to say that it doesn't matter what OS you have, bacause this process is OS indipendent. When you access BIOS, your OS is not even loaded yet.